# Correct file paths for Inkscape snap command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, inkscape, snap

I'm trying to use the Inkscape snap provided in Ubuntu from the command line, but it fails to access my files.

Using the graphical interface to open files in Inkscape works well. However, it always forgets my last opened directory.

Should I use another path to correctly access the files from within the snap? In the Inkscape open file dialog I don't see any specific prefix.

I see in snap connections that personal-files are mounted(?).

```
thomas@box:~$ inkscape --export-width=16 --export-height=16 -o ~/trash/16x16.png ~/trash/base.svg
Gtk-Message: 07:58:28.269: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 07:58:28.315: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 07:58:28.317: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ink_file_open: '/home/thomas/trash/base.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/thomas/trash/base.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
(07:58)
```

```
thomas@box:~$ ls /home/thomas/trash/base.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas 32K dec  1 07:57 /home/thomas/trash/base.svg
(07:58)
```

```
thomas@box:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
(07:59)
```

```
thomas@box:~$ snap connections inkscape
Interface              Plug                          Slot                            Notes
content[gtk-3-themes]  inkscape:gtk-3-themes         gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]   inkscape:icon-themes          gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
dbus                   -                             inkscape:inkscape-dbus          -
desktop                inkscape:desktop              :desktop                        -
desktop-legacy         inkscape:desktop-legacy       :desktop-legacy                 -
gsettings              inkscape:gsettings            :gsettings                      -
network                inkscape:network              :network                        -
personal-files         inkscape:dot-config-inkscape  :personal-files                 -
raw-usb                inkscape:raw-usb              -                               -
unity7                 inkscape:unity7               :unity7                         -
wayland                inkscape:wayland              :wayland                        -
x11                    inkscape:x11                  :x11                            -
(07:59)
```

```
thomas@box:~$ snap info inkscape
name:      inkscape
summary:   Vector Graphics Editor
publisher: Inkscape Project (inkscape✓)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/inkscape
contact:   https://inkscape.org/en/community/mailing-lists/#inkscape-user
license:   GPL-3.0
description: |
  A Free and open source vector graphics editor. It offers a rich set of features and is widely used
  for both artistic and technical illustrations such as cartoons, clip art, logos, typography,
  diagramming and flowcharting.
  
  
  
  It uses vector graphics to allow for sharp printouts and renderings at unlimited resolution and is
  not bound to a fixed number of pixels like raster graphics. Inkscape uses the standardized SVG
  file format as its main format, which is supported by many other applications including web
  browsers.
  
  
  
  Inkscape supports many advanced SVG features (markers, clones, alpha blending,
  etc.) and great care is taken in designing a streamlined interface.
  It is very easy to edit nodes, perform complex path operations, trace
  bitmaps and much more.
  We also aim to maintain a thriving user and developer community by using
  open, community-oriented development.
commands:
  - inkscape
  - inkscape.viewer
snap-id:      tIrcA87dMWthuDORCCRU0VpidK5SBVOc
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 8 days ago, at 06:49 CET
channels:
  latest/stable:    1.2.1-8a69933317-2022-10-28-cust 2022-11-04 (10462) 344MB -
  latest/candidate: 1.2.1-f926fb465e-2022-11-30-cust 2022-12-01 (10502) 345MB -
  latest/beta:      ↑                                                         
  latest/edge:      1.3-dev-74adff3496-2022-05-26    2022-05-26 (10408) 322MB -
installed:          1.2.1-8a69933317-2022-10-28-cust            (10462) 344MB -
```

edit.
From the Export pane, I see that my file resides here in this instance: `/run/user/1000/doc/53892325/base.svg`
And selecting the output location, I get `/run/user/1000/doc/7f5d9c6d/base_32x32.png`

Running `mount`, I see this:
`portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)`